# Is there a way to connect Cosmos DB pre-trigger to an Azure function or WebJob?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, database-trigger

I have a collection of some documents with a ttl (Time To Leave value) value which is not equal to -1. I want to send document data to an Azure function or WebJobs before the document is removed from the database. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe look at change feed - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed

> The change feed includes inserts and update operations made to documents within the collection. You can capture deletes by setting a "soft-delete" flag within your documents in place of deletes. **Alternatively, you can set a finite expiration period for your documents via the TTL capability, for example, 24 hours and use the value of that property to capture deletes.** With this solution, you have to process changes within a shorter time interval than the TTL expiration period.

[image: Change feed diagram]

Comment: I have already added TTL capability. What I try to do is taking another action, before the document is deleted.  Such as sending a message with the information that comes from the deleted document.

Comment: You've just described soft delete. Use it.

Comment: I managed to fire the pre-trigger by removing a document from the collection manually. But what I want is firing the trigger with TTL. So do you say that it isn't possible? Because in order to fire the trigger, I have added the id of the trigger into options parameter of removeItem function.